# Need guidance on extending my root partition

Tags: partitioning, root

I'm in a bit of trouble right now and would like advice on what to do.
I have 4.63GB partitioned for my root partition, and as of right now I have 0 space available. My swap space is 14.90GB. Is it possible to to segregate my swap space in order to extend my root partition? I can't even take a screenshot as I have no space left.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T36Ys.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

1. Open `GParted` from a Live environment.
2. Right-click on `linux-swap`, i.e., `/dev/sda7` and click on `Resize/Move`.
3. Next, in the space beside `Free space preceding (MiB):` enter the amount of `space` in `MB` that you want to allocate to your `root` partition.
4. Now, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then, click on `Resize/Move`.
5. Now, right-click on the partition that says `/dev/sda6`, i.e., `ext4` and click on `Resize/Move`.
6. Drag the `arrow` on the right side till it fills up all the `greyed` space.

   [image: 1]
7. Click on `Resize/Move`.
8. Finally, click on `Apply` and you will have what you desired.
9. Shut-down your live environment and boot your PC.

Comment: Oh, of course. I did it on Free space following instead of proceeding. That makes sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad! I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB. Boot with it. Run, in a terminal, `sudo gparted`. This will open the GParted partition manager. Make sure your main disk is selected in the tab GParted > Devices (it should be /dev/sda). You'll see the swap and Ubuntu's ext4 partitions. Right-click the swap partition and click "resize". Shrink it to the wanted size and click OK. This will leave you with an unallocated space; Now right-click the Ubuntu ext4 partition and you will be able to increase its size. After doing it, click in the green colored "apply" button to apply your changes. That should do it.

Comment: So according to my image, the main disk would be /dec/sda3 right?

Comment: Okay now I'm here 
http://i.imgur.com/FfMr9Nl.png
I believe my unallocated partition must be under the root partition?

Comment: No, the unallocated space does not need to be right under your root partition. That should do it. But, aside from that, do you really need a 9 GB swap partition?

Comment: I'm not sure. I followed the 2x RAM rule when initially partitioning this duoboot system.
Anyway, it's not letting me resize with the unallocated space.

http://i.imgur.com/jCKNVOg.png